# Roots of an equation

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

The problem I'm working with:

> As mentioned in the book, the quadratic polynomial $P(x) = x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_2}$ Hence, we can form the Galois field $$F = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$
>
> Let $\alpha$ be the "Galois imaginary" associated for this field - that is, an element such that $$\alpha^2+\alpha+1 = 0$$
>
> Find all the roots of the equation $x^2+\alpha = 0$ in $F$.

Here is my thought process:

Since $P(x)$ is a quadratic equation, it can have at most $2$ roots and let those $2$ roots be called $r_1$ and $r_2$. So we need to find these two roots such that $$x^2+\alpha+1 = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$ So since we are working in $\mathbb{Z_2}$, I can write $$\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$$
Then we have

$\alpha^3 = \alpha^2\cdot \alpha = (\alpha+1)(\alpha) = \alpha^2+\alpha = (\alpha+1)+ \alpha = 1$

Therefore, $\alpha$ has order 3 and we have $x = \pm (1+\alpha)$. However, my friend told me that I didn't specify which element of the field F is $-(1+\alpha)$ What does he mean by this? Also, is my thought process correct?

Comment: You don't need $-$  signs in a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Oh duh! I'm working in $\mathbb{Z_2}$. Other than that, how is my work? Anything else that I need to add?

Comment: I don't understand how you derive the root is $1+\alpha$ ((which is true, anyway).

Comment: I based it off the fact that $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$. Or, perhaps, I was just lucky to guess the root (I'll go with the latter reasoning). How would one approach it differently then?

Comment: If $\alpha$ has a square root, it can be only $1\alpha$, since obviously, neither $\alpha$, nor $1$, nor $0$ can be this square root. Now check: $(1+\alpha)^2=1^2+\alpha^2=\dots$.

Comment: I would be $\alpha$.

Comment: Exactly. There was a typo in my previous comment: for $1\alpha$, I meant $1+\alpha$, of course.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now.